# Как узнать список исключений boost::from_iso_string() в модуле date_time?

Tags: c++, исключения, boost, время, boost-date-time

Пробую использовать **boost/date_time**. Для получения `ptime` из строки использую `boost::from_iso_string()`, из документации:

```
std::string ts("20020131T235959");
ptime t(from_iso_string(ts))
```

Далее, при подаче на вход функции пустой строки жду исключение (возможно то же с некорректно сформированной). При этом перехватывается `std::exception` (по крайней мере для пустой строки), но хочется точно знать, что за исключение. Документация TL;DR. Прошелся по верхам, но про исключения не нашел. Как узнать, какие конкретно исключения генерирует функция `ptime from_iso_string(std::string)`?

P.S. Пошел смотреть исходники, обнаружил что `ptime from_iso_string(std::string)` вызывает `parse_iso_time(const std::string& s, char sep)`, далее `parse_undelimited_date<date_type>(date_string)`, где строка передается в **tokenizer**. Потом итератором токенайзера ходит по контейнеру (например, пустому), но где исключение, не понял.

UPD

Вызов `boost::from_iso_string()` с пустой строкой генерирует исключение `std::out_of_range` (см. `std::exception::what()`).

UPD2

В случае некорректной строки, как понятно из справки (а именно из раздела [**Library Reference**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time/doxy.html#header.boost.date_time.gregorian.greg_date_hpp)), генерируются `bad_day_of_month`, `bad_day_of_year`, `bad_month`, `bad_year` из области видимости `boost::gregorian`.

Из практических наблюдений, строка вида `20160412T235990` парсится токенайзером, преобразовывается из строки boost::lexical_cast. Поэтому некорректная строка вида `20160412TT35990` вызовет `boost::bad_lexical_cast`; строка вида `0160412T235990` (пропущен первый символ) будет считываться как **0160**(год)**41**(месяц)**2**(день), откуда генерируется `boost::gregorian::bad_month`, унаследованный от `std::out_of_range`.

Одним словом, RTFM (read the **friendly** manual, конечно).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внимательно читать документацию. Классы исключений описаны в файлах в каталоге **boost/date_time/gregorian/** и соответственно в онлайн-справке (см. [Library Reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time/doxy.html#header.boost.date_time.gregorian.greg_date_hpp)).